# [NodeJS]Converting Exponential to Non Exponential without using any libraries or builtin functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I was just wondering on how to convert an exponential value ex. 1.1111111101111111e+30 to 1111111110111111105345512013824 without the use of any libraries or built in function in NodeJS. need help in understanding how BigInt() converts it. Thank you.

Comment: See https://tc39.es/ecma262/#%E2%84%9D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After converting the exponential value number to binary, with `Number.toString(2)`, just read the string as a normal binary integer. The least significant bit is at the end, so we do that in reversed order.

```js
const tobigint = number => {
  const bin = number.toString(2);
  let result = 0n, current = 1n;
  for (let i = bin.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (bin[i] == '1') result += current;
    current *= 2n;
  }
  return number >= 0 ? result : -result;
}

const num = 1.1242241e+30;
console.log(tobigint(num));
```

Comment: Thank you, though I'm still understanding the logic for this and why it needs to be converted to binary.

Comment: @VIRUS471 Now that I thought more about it, there's actually probably a better way, and I just overcomplicated it by using binary. Will come in a few minutes with a simpler answer.

Comment: @VIRUS471 If you like this kind of things, like, how numbers are represented in binary form, and how the computer interprets them, I would recommend trying that in C/C++. It is much easier that way, and JavaScript provides an advanced API, but doesn't let you do actually anything you want with it.